# What are the differences between C-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++03, variable-initialization

To the best of my knowledge, there are three ways to initialize a variable in C++.

```
int x = 0;    // C-like initialization
int x (0);    // Constructor initialization
int x {0};    // Uniform initialization
```

The uniform initialization was brought on for [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) to provide a more uniform syntax for initializing different types of variables, which required different syntax in [C++03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03).

What are the differences between C-like, constructor, and uniform initialization? And should I always use the uniform initialization?

Comment: What do you mean by difference? For a basic data type like int, they are exactly the same. I would use "C-like" for int as that is the most intuitive way.

Comment: I am new to C++ but I'm thinking along the lines of what's happening behind the hood. I'm reading on it, but I assume the constructor initialization calls a constructor method in an object. What happens in that constructor? I also heard that the uniform initialization method will fallback to the constructor initialization in some instances.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, I would recommend looking at the [following talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKYcybUEX3I) by Herb Sutter, in which he gives some recommendations about the subject. The brace-initialization discussion starts at [around 23:00](http://youtu.be/yKYcybUEX3I?t=23m).

When you are talking about primitive data types, all 3 yield the same result. I personally prefer sticking with the old `int x = 0` syntax, but it comes down to personal preference.

For class types, brace initialization and old-school constructor initialization are not completely interchangeable. For example:

```
vector<int> v (100); // Creates a 100-element vector
vector<int> v {100}; // Creates a 1-element vector, holding the value 100.
```

This is because `std::vector` has a constructor that explicitly defines `std::initializer_list` as its only argument. Keep in mind that

```
auto var = {1, 2};
```

creates a `std::initializer_list`, with `var` as its identifier.

The thing about initializer lists is that they provide consistency that is a welcome change from what was available beforehand. For example, if you were to initialize an array in C++, you would use:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

But, if you wanted to initialize a `vector<int>` with the same elements, you either had to:

1. Initialize the above arr first and then pass `arr` and `arr + 4`
2. Create the vector and push_back() the elements individually or in a loop.

With C++11, you could just use

```
vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // Same syntax. Nice! Note that the = is optional
```

Another instance in which brace initialization is helpful is that it provides a workaround to C++'s [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). From the talk, assume that we have two classes, `origin` and `extents`, whose instances can be passed to construct another object of type `rectangle`. The following statement:

```
rectangle w(origin(), extents());
```

doesn't allow you to create a `rectangle` object using `origin` and `extents` temporaries, because that statement is parsed as a function declaration. Tsk tsk. So normally, you would have to do:

```
origin  o;
extents e;
rectangle w(o, e);
```

With brace initialization, you can create them on the fly, and

```
rectangle w {origin(), extents()};
```

will work as intended, i.e. passed to the constructor which is overloaded with an `origin` object as it's first argument and an `extents` object as the second.

The rule is for objects, use brace initialiation unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: I still don't get it. As I read somewhere, C++ will interpret it as a function declaration if it looks like one. Both `rectangle w(origin(), extents());` and `rectangle w(o, e);` look like function declarations, what is the difference between them?

Comment: @Cupidvogel the second example is not a function declaration, because you do not have the types of the parameters there. `o` and `e` are instances of `origin` and `extents`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, but the first one is also similar, right? `o` is actually `origin()`, so both don't have types, right?

Comment: Not quite. the `origin()` in `rectangle w(origin(), extents())` is parsed as a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns an `origin` object. Same with `extents()`. So they are types.

Comment: *"[...] about primitive data types, all 3 yield the same result."* - This is not 100% true since brace-initialization do not allow narrowing conversions while the others does (`char c(999);` is valid while `char c{999};` is not for 8-bits `char`). You also do not mention that `T x = ...` performs a copy-initialization (that, I agree, most compilers would elide).

Comment: Agreed with Holt, there are nuances missing here, especially that of copy-initialisation. Also: In C++17, `auto thing{1}` will deduce an `int`,  `auto thing = {1}` or `= {1, 2}` an  `std::initializer_list`, and `auto thing{1, 2}` is disallowed. This has been done so that uniform initialisation can be used with `auto` in a more intuitive way. GCC already does this for C++ <17, but Clang doesn't. Paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html

Comment: Since brace-initialization and direct-initialization have different semantics in the container-like case, it’s quite reasonable to say that one should use the former for, and (aside from tricks like working around the most vexing parse) only for, expressing **assembly** from components rather than **computation** (of a class-type value) from parameters.  Even `T()` and `T{}` differ in certain aggregate cases, so the only general advice is “use the one you mean”.

Comment: @nasser-sh but then, what if there are types named `o` and `e` ? Does C++ parsing depend on the names in scope?

Answer (score 18):

> What are the differences between c-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?

For primitive types like `int`, there's no practical difference; so let's consider a class type `T` instead.

The first style is equivalent to

```
T x(T(0));
```

creating a temporary object from the initialiser expression, and then initialising `x` by moving or copying that. In practice, the move or copy will be elided, so that the result is the same as the second style; the only difference is that the first will fail if there isn't an accessible copy or move constructor.

The second directly initialises the object using a constructor that takes one argument, giving an error if there's no suitable constructor.

The third depends on what constructors are available.

- if there's a constructor taking `std::initializer_list`, it uses that;
- otherwise, if there's a constructor taking a single argument of a suitable type, it uses that;
- otherwise, if it's an aggregate (with no constructors) with one member, that member is initialised with zero;
- otherwise, it's an error.

> And should I always use the uniform initialization?

No. Sometimes you need function-style initialisation to distinguish between an `initializer_list` constructor and one taking other argument types. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v1(10, 42);  // 10 elements with value 42
std::vector<int> v2{10, 42};  // 2 elements with values 10 and 42
```

You also shouldn't call it "uniform initialisation" since it's not "uniform" in any meaningful sense. The official term is "brace-initialisation".

Comment: `T x = 0;` will also fail if the constructor `T(int)` is marked as explicit (which is a common thing for some standard containers!).

Comment: Did you make an error in this statement? "if it's an aggregate (with no constructors) with one member, that member is initialised with zero;" ? I don't get it

Comment: @PatrickParker I think he means, for example, if you have `struct Thing { int value };`, and you didn't manually write a constructor for it, then writing `Thing t{0}` will construct a `t` of type `Thing`, whose only member `int value` will be initialised to `0`. @MikeSeymour correct me if I'm wrong. (I'm no expert in C++.)