# What is the different between these object initializations?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){
        std::cout << "Called Constructer A \n";
    }
    MyClass(int n){
        std::cout << "Called Constructer B \n";
    }
};
int main(){
    MyClass a(); //It's not works as expect
    MyClass b(0); //But this works
    MyClass c;
    MyClass d = MyClass();
    MyClass e = MyClass(0);

}
```

So how does `e` differ from `b`, and why `b` works but not `a`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of a few questions

Comment: Great - Not only you require an answer but for us to write the question!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24953658/981959 and [tag:most-vexing-parse]. Please search before creating new questions

Comment: @EdHeal: It is not a request, because of my limited English, I am not able to write a formal question, so I just hope someone to edit my question to benefit other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is declared as a function that returns a MyClass

`b` is the normal way to construct with an int parameter

`c` is the normal way to construct with no parameters

`d` requires an accessible copy (/move)-constructor as technically it copies the temporary on the RHS into `d` but the compiler might not actually invoke it.

`e` is the same but uses the int constructor. If you did

```
MyClass e = 0;
```

that would also require for the constructor that takes an int to be non-explicit.

To answer the question "How does e differ from b". The two objects are alike, but the construction you use with `e` would fail to compile if your class did not have an accessible copy/move constructor. (Move constructor in C++11)

b does not appear to declare a function so doesn't fail unlike a.

In C++03 if you put in

```
class MyClass {

     // etc.
  private:
      MyClass( const MyClass& );
};
```

The compiler would complain on the lines that create `d` and `e`

In C++11

```
 class MyClass {
      // etc.

      // this can be public too
      MyClass( MyClass&& ) = delete;
 };
```

would invoke a compiler error "use of deleted function" when you try to create `d` and `e`.
The private copy constructor would also yield the error unless you did:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass(){
        std::cout << "Called Constructer A \n";
    }
    MyClass(int n){
        std::cout << "Called Constructer B \n";
    }

    MyClass( MyClass const&) = delete; // cannot copy
    MyClass( MyClass && ) = default; // but you CAN move

};
```

Now your code will compile.

Whilst we are on the subject of constructors in C++11, you can also have:

```
   MyClass f{}; // not a function
   MyClass g{1};
   MyClass h = MyClass{};
   MyClass i = MyClass{0};
   MyClass j = {};
   MyClass k = {0};
```

Note that if I change my move constructor (currently =default) to

```
       MyClass( MyClass && ) 
      { 
          std::cout << "Moved\n";
      }
```

I tried it and "Moved" never printed. The compiler can (and did) optimise it away. But it has to be accessible.