# What does the second parameter mean in this signature?

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<int> interpret(const std::string &src, const std::vector<int> &input = {});
```

I understand everything about the signature except setting the reference input to {}. What does that mean?

Comment: See also [What are the differences between c-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization).

Comment: In general, `{}` is a "good default" for the type. It's 0 for `int`, `double`, `char`, pointers, etc, applied to each element in the case of arrays, applied to each member in the case of C structures, and typically the user-chosen default for other classes (e.g., an empty string or vector).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `=` introduces a default value for the parameter... `{}` in this case indicates an empty `vector`.  Consequently, you can invoke the function with one argument, and `input` will be empty.