# Understanding the weird syntax with curly braces in a constructor initializer list

Tags: c++

So I was just browsing the source code of a library when I encountered this.

```
Font::Font(const sf::Font& font) :
        m_font{std::make_shared<sf::Font>(font)}
    {
    }
```

I don't understand the syntax

```
m_font{..}
```

What is it? What does it do. I am sorry if this is really stupid question. I don't know what to Google, so asking here.

Comment: try googling: initializer list braces

Comment: Are you asking about the initializer brace list, or are you asking about the make_shared? Google shared pointers if the latter.

Comment: Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is described on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), but in a somewhat hard to read format:

> The body of a function definition of any constructor, before the opening brace of the compound statement, may include the *member initializer list*, whose syntax is the colon character `:`, followed by the comma-separated list of one or more *member-initializers*, each of which has the following syntax
>
> ...
>
> *class-or-identifier brace-init-list* (2) <sub>(since C++11)</sub>
>
> ...
>
> 2) Initializes the base or member named by *class-or-identifier* using list-initialization (which becomes value-initialization if the list is empty and aggregate-initialization when initializing an aggregate)

What this is trying to say is that `X::X(...) : some_member{some_expressions} { ... }` causes the `some_member` class member to be initialised from `some_expressions`. Given

```
struct X {
    Y y;
    X() : y{3} {}
};
```

the data member `y` will be initialised the exact same way a local variable `Y y{3};` would be initialised.

In your case, `std::make_shared<sf::Font>(font)` produces the value that will be used to initialise the `m_font` class member.

Comment: This begs the question: Why would you use braces instead of parenthesis for initialization?

Comment: @wingleader See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization).

Comment: And what would one put in the curly braces after initializing the variables?

Answer (score 9):

That is a [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) aka brace initializer list. More specifically, in this case it's a direct-list initialization.

Basically the `m_font` variable is initialized with the value that's given in the curly braces, in this case it's initialized to a `shared_ptr` for the `font` object that's given to the constructor.

Answer (score 7):

The class `Font` has a member called `m_font` of type `std::shared_ptr<sf::Font>`, so in the constructor of the class `Font` that member is being initialized with a shared pointer to `font`.