# struct initialisation syntax

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, declaration

I stumbled over a piece of syntax that I have not seen yet and didn't find online, and I wonder what this is:

```
constexpr struct X{ /* define X members and methods */ } Y{};
```

What i don't understand is the Y{}.

Comment: which part you dont understand? One could write a full article about that single line covering c-heritage up to latest c++ features.

Comment: What is `something`? What does it look like?

Comment: `struct X{ /* something here */}`  defines a struct   `constexpr Y` creates that struct that's a compile time constant called Y   `{};`  initialises the values in the struct

Comment: @UKMonkey I'd make your comment an answer and link to another question that asks about list initialization. Maybe these questions help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212130/understanding-the-weird-syntax-with-curly-braces-in-a-constructor-initializer-li/41212196 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives.

Comment: ref. [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constexpr struct X{ /* something here */} Y{};
```

is equal to

```
struct X{ /* something here */};

constexpr X Y{};
```

For `constexpr`, check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) documentation.

Comment: thank you! I missed the fact that you can initialize directly with {}.