# White spaces in naming a class?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I was through the source of wxWidgets when I saw this code

```
class WXDLLIMPEXP_FWD_CORE wxKeyEvent;
```

After this they defined a class like this

```
class WXDLLIMPEXP_FWD_CORE wxKeyEvent : public wxEvent{
//some code
};
```

As you can see there is a white space, but you cannot have it while naming the class, further I wrote this small code which compiles successfully `

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class a
{
public:
    int x;  
};

class a b
{
    // it fails if i add anything there
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile when I add something inside class a b. Could you please tell me what's going on?

Thank you!

Comment: `WXDLLIMPEXP_FWD_CORE` is a macro.  I guess it becomes white space so it really isn't part of the name

Comment: @Nathan Not really expands to whitespace.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if these things are windows related then do you know how do they handle gtk,osx related events ?

Comment: Probably by defining different class attributes (or whitespace) suitable for these platforms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WXDLLIMPEXP_FWD_CORE` is a macro that is supposed to add a (compiler specific) class attribute and expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` depending if used to export or import the class.

You example `class a b { /* ... */ };` is simply invalid syntax,

Class names cannot contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right regarding the macro definition, but also misleading regarding the "invalid syntax".

`class a b { /* ... */ };` actually **is** valid syntax if your compiler supports [uniform initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization). In the code you present it causes a variable of type `a` named `b` to be constructed in the global namespace using the default constructor. The `class` keyword works like `typename` in this case and the code should compile even without it.

It stops compiling when you try to define a variable inside the brackets since that's where uniform initialization syntax expects constructor call arguments to be placed.