# C++ Tokenizer using istream_iterator

Tags: c++

This is a question regarding an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/1061193).

The following tokenizes a `string`:

```
string sentence = "And I feel fine...";
istringstream iss(sentence);
vector<string> tokens{istream_iterator<string>{iss},
                      istream_iterator<string>{}};
```

What does the last line mean? What is the purpose of the `{}`.

Comment: [Default constructed input stream iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator) using uniform initialization. The same as `istream_iterator<string>()`. Good discussion of Uniform Initialization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization

Comment: @user4581301 Very informative. I really need to get with the times. Thank you.

Comment: Your question title doesn't really have much to do with what you're actually asking about... I came here looking for how to tokenize using an `istream_iterator` and found a question about uniform initialization instead, lol