# error: request for member '..' in '..' , which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization, most-vexing-parse, variable-initialization

I use an STL `priority_queue` and give a custom comparator class whose constructor takes in the pointer to the vector that stores the priorities, thus -

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>          // std::priority_queue
#include <vector>         // std::vector

using namespace std;

class CompareReachDist
{
    const vector<float> *reach_dists;
public:
    CompareReachDist(const vector<float> *input)
    {
        reach_dists = input;
    }

    bool operator() (const size_t &l, const size_t &r) const
    {
        return (reach_dists->at(l) > reach_dists->at(r));
    }
};

typedef priority_queue<size_t, vector<size_t>, CompareReachDist> pq;
vector<float> reach_dists;

int main()
{
    pq seeds(CompareReachDist(&reach_dists));
    bool isEmpty = seeds.empty();

  return 0;
}
```

However, on compiling I get the error:

```
error: request for member 'empty' in 'seeds', which is of non-class type 'pq(CompareReachDist&) {aka std::priority_queue<unsigned int std::vector<unsigned int>, CompareReachDist>(CompareReachDist&)}'
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a parsing issue. Let's break it apart:

```
CompareReachDist(&reach_dists)
```

You may think this creates a temporary `CompareReachDist` with the address of the static `reach_dists`. But in the context of the overall declaration it is interpreted as a reference to a `CompareReachDist`. Strange, but that is because, roughly speaking, the grammar of C++ favors function declarations to object declaration. The following

```
pq seeds(CompareReachDist(&reach_dists));
```

Is an overall declaration of a function. It accepts a `CompareReachDist&` and returns a `pq`.

The error you receive is because, quite obviously, a function doesn't have an `empty` member you can call.

The solution since C++11 is to favor list initialization, which breaks the ambiguity and its resolution as a function declaration. So you can do this:

```
pq seeds{CompareReachDist{&reach_dists}};
```

And get an object, as one would expect.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now. How do you think should I restructure my object declaration such that the compiler no longer takes it for a function declaration ?

Comment: @ameya.dubey - Well, prefer C++11 initialization syntax. Or introduce a named variable for the `CompareReachDist` parameter.

Comment: @ameya.dubey - Indeed you do. Glad to be of help.

Comment: @ameya.dubey Maybe you would like to read about C++11 initialization syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24954259/8254699).

Comment: @FilipKočica - Yes, that is most helpful. The initialization list syntax fixed it right away.

Comment: @StoryTeller Minor nitpick - Wikipedia and other answers seem to indicate that `CompareReachDist(&reach_dists)` is interpreted as a pointer to a function that takes a `vector<float>*` and returns a `CompareReachDist`, rather than a reference to a `CompareReachDist`.

Comment: @ameya.dubey - It isn't. For one, `CompareReachDist(&reach_dists)` has no mention of `vector<float>*`. `&reach_dists` doesn't mean the type `vector<float>*`. Secondly, parentheses,  even superfluous ones, are [allowed in variable/parameter declarations](https://ideone.com/ocip5v). And finally, if you don't believe me yet, check the compiler error. What type does it see for the parameter.

Comment: @StoryTeller - The compiler error agrees with you, so it is definitely a reference to a `CompareReachDist`. Does the compiler think that `reach_dists` is a reference to some `CompareReachDist` ? If so, why doesn't it realize that there's already a `reach_dists` of type `vector<float>` declared globally ?

Comment: @ameya.dubey - Because the compiler already parses it as a function declaration, the same as if you had written `pq seeds(CompareReachDist(&));`.  To it `reach_dists` is just how you (optionally) name the parameter. It doesn't conflict.

Comment: @StoryTeller Of course, it's crystal clear now. You can declare but not define functions inside other functions, and the compiler ignores the parameter names, keeping only the types. The parentheses are then superfluous. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Holy crap, using {} instead of () really blows my mind. I've stuck here for an afternoon