# Initializing object and pointer object using uniform initialization does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, object, initialization

so I am stuck at something that I think is easy.

Note: everything below is for C++11 and above.

---

Let us start. I have a class named "Employee". Its consctructor is as follows:

```
Employee::Employee(const string& first, const string& last, const string& ssn)
      : firstName(first), lastName(last), socialSecurityNumber(ssn) {}
```

---

Furthermore, when trying to create the object, in my main, I do the following:

```
void main()
{
string firstName;
string lastName;
string socialSec;
Employee salariedEmployee{firstName, lastName, socialSec};
}
```

and I get the error:

> error: cannot declare variable 'salariedEmployee' to be of abstract
>   type 'Employee'

---

then I tried to create my object as a pointer, as followes:

```
Employee *salariedEmployee{&firstName, &lastName, &socialSec};
```

and get the error:

> error: scalar object 'salariedEmployee' requires one element in initializer

---

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I was used to coding is previous versions of C++11 but I am trying to learn these new tricks of using curly braces (uniform initialization). What am I doing wrong (in both cases)?

P.S. I have googled a lot but I am very confused about what to do. Two of the resourses I saved are these (but have read much more stuff):

- https://arne-mertz.de/2015/07/new-c-features-uniform-initialization-and-initializer_list/
- [What are the differences between C-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization)

Comment: your `Employee` has pure virtual functions (abstract type). It's not related to uniform initialization

Comment: @appleapple Or it is derived from an abstract base class and has not implemented the full interface. Either way, the error is elsewhere than Dimitris Pantelis expects.

Comment: @Jodocus yor are right :) I forgot that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error: cannot declare variable 'salariedEmployee' to be of abstract type 'Employee'

This error is not related to the way you call your constructor. It just says you are trying to instantiate a type which has not been completely defined, some of its methods are pure virtuals.

For instance, this works:

```
#include <string>

struct Employee
{
    Employee(const std::string& first, const std::string& last, const std::string& ssn);

    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string socialSecurityNumber;
};

Employee::Employee(const std::string& first, const std::string& last, const std::string& ssn)
    : firstName(first), lastName(last), socialSecurityNumber(ssn)
{}

int main()
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string socialSec;
    Employee bob{firstName, lastName, socialSec};
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b14917fd69d42115)

But if you add a pure virtual `fire` method to `Employee`, it will fail to compile: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97cc9b87a2ab9306).

Comment: You are right. In the Employee there is the like "   virtual double earnings() const = 0; // pure virtual". It even says that it is a pure virtual but did not know exactly what that did and how it was used. Employee is indeed intended to be a base class for "SalariedEmployee" class. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Although it works fine on my computer. In your case the problem can be the `uniform initialization`. Basically, the constructor is a a special kind of `class Method`(function, sort-of).

So, the way to pass arguments to a function is by parentheses `()` ,not by uniform initialization.

Comment: I down-voted your answer because this is simply not the case. The error message gives it away ;)