# How Structures are initialized in C++

Tags: c++, structure

I am reading TCPPPL by Stroustrup. An exerxise in the book goes somewhat like this:

```
struct X{
    int i;
    X(int);
    X operator+(int);
};

struct Y{
    int i;
    Y(X);
    Y operator+(X);
    operator int();
};

extern X operator* (X,Y);
extern int f(X);
X x=1;
Y y=x;
int i=2;
int main()
{
//main body
}
```

My question (maybe a trivial one) is that what is happening in the line: X x =1;? Is a variable x of type struct X being initialized, i.e. its ***i*** is being given the value 1? If so, why are there no curly braces around 1?

Comment: This can be done because `X(int);` is not declared as `explicit`.

Comment: Somehow a duplicate to [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean), different question, but should explain everything.

Comment: It initializes an `X` `x` with an `int` `1`. There are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24953658/3484570) to do that.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that the book doesn't explain this.

Comment: @molbdnilo: maybe the book explained it somewhere but I didn't read the text.

Comment: @Birbal The text is the most important part. Why did you get a book if you're not going to read it?

Comment: @molbdnilo I am reading the book but I jumped at this exercise, I'll continue reading the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question (maybe a trivial one) is that what is happening in the line: X x =1;

X defines a constructor that takes one int: `X::X(int i)`

The statement:

```
X x = 1;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
X x = X(1);
```

or

```
auto x = X(1);
```

or

```
auto x = X { 1 };
```

i.e. construct an X using the (int) constructor.

> i.e. its i is being given the value 1?

Yes, that's correct**.

** or at least that's what I assume, not having seen the constructor's definition. I have assumed it looks something like this:

```
X::X(int arg)
: i(arg)
{
}
```

Comment: "its i is being given the value 1?" No, it depends on how the constructor is implemented.

Comment: The statement `X x = 1` is not equivalent to `X x = X(1)`, otherwise both would work for `explicit X(int)`. In the given code they have the same result, because the constructor is not explicit.

Comment: @t.niese *in this case* they are equivalent, because they refer to `X`.