# what is the difference between i{1} and i(1) in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I noted that I can create on object in two ways:

```
struct A
{ 
      int a;
      A(int i)
      {
          a=i;
      }
}

A i(1);
A i{1};
```

What is the difference between them and which one to use?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax

Comment: The second version avoids the vexing parse problem also prevents narrowing.

Comment: This is 100% a dupe.

Comment: This post explains it pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization