# What are curly braces in hash function?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, it is possible to get a hashed value for a `string` variable as follows:

```
std::size_t h1 = std::hash<std::string>{}("Some_String");
```

It is clean and simple. However, I have two questions:

1. Why do we need the curly braces here?
2. Is it possible to escape using the braces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between C-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization)

Comment: Note that `std::hash` instances are _types_, not functions. This, e.g., allows to specialize `std::hash` for user-defined types in the `std` namespace, which will no longer be allowed for _template functions_ in C++20.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The curly braces are used to value-initialize an object of type `std::hash<std::string>`. That object can then be called, since it has an overloaded `operator()`. Alternatively, you could create a named object:

```
std::hash<std::string> H;
auto h1 = H("Some_String");
```