# Is it possible to put multiple names in one string?

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ and I'm currently following a tutorial on YouTube.

I thought it was fun to make a very simple 'access' program. If I type in my name it says, "Welcome!" If I type in another name it says, "access denied". It worked perfectly fine, but then I wanted the program to say "Welcome!" to two different names. So, I wanted to add a second name in the string, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I googled a lot but I couldn't find anything. In the end, I came to `string name = ("Joe", "Sean");`, but here, it was only valid for Sean. I just can't figure out how to put multiple names in one string and make them both work. I hope you can help me, here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;




int main()
{
    string name = ("Joe", "Sean");
    string input;
    cout << "What is your name?\nMy name is: ";
    cin >> input;



    if(input == name){
        cout << "Welcome, "<< input <<"! ";

    } else {
        cout << "Access denied";
    }



    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to only greet people whose names appear in a set of names?

Comment: To extend what @SamVarshavchik wrote there, the art of googling is posing the right question, and the art of research is questioning the source you have. (i.e. find a better source to learn C++ from)

Comment: I think you should follow that tutorial (or some [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) ;] )a bit further until they cover vectors, arrays and other stl-containers. Right now you've arrived at a solution that is definitely not what you want, see also: [How does the comma operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work). And I think just giving you some code would confuse you more than if you learned it on your own.

Comment: What you probably want is a `std::vector<std::string> names = { "Joe", "Sean" };` and `std::find()`.

Comment: What πάνταῥεῖ said, though it looks like you want `std::any_of`.

Comment: Or an `unordered_set<string>` and `contains()`.

Comment: Learn about what the comma operator does. It's not what you expect. Also a std::string can hold a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the string variable "name". You need an array of strings, not a single string.

This is an example implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string names[] = {"Joe", "Sean"};

    string input;
    cout << "What is your name?\nMy name is: ";
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < end(names) - begin(names); i++) {
      if(input == names[i]){
          cout << "Welcome, "<< input <<"! " << endl;
          return 0;
      }
    }

    cout << "Access denied" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You encountered some quirky features of C++ in the approach you are using to initialize your string variable:

```
string s1 = ("Joe"); // creates a string "Joe"
string s2 = ("Joe", "Sean"); // creates 2 strings, "Joe" and "Sean", and the variable s2 stores only the latter!
```

For more details on the different methods for initializing variables there has been an interesting discussion in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization).

Comment: I would recommend using `std::size(names)` instead of `end(names) - begin(names)` - or `std::distance(begin(names), end(names))` - or better, use a range-based for-loop: `for(auto& name : names) { if(input == name) ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do it using a vector of strings, so you can adapt easily with more names :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void printMessage(string message)
{
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> names{"Joe", "Sean", "Paul"};
    string input;
    cout << "What is your name? " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    for (string name : names)
    {
        if (name == input)
        {
            printMessage("Welcome!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printMessage("Access Denied!");

    return 0;
}
```