# Using Curly Brackets and Parentheses

Tags: c++

So i'm doing a beginner c++ course and i'm confused about something regarding parenthesis and curly brackets..

```
#include "Savings_Account.h"

Savings_Account::Savings_Account(double balance, double int_rate)
    : Account(balance), int_rate{int_rate} {
        
    }

Savings_Account::Savings_Account() 
    : Savings_Account{0.0, 0.0} {
        
    }
```

**Note:Savings_account is a class derived from Account class**

In the second line of code where the tutor writes **:Account(balance)**, he says he is delegating to the account class's overloaded constructor which kinda makes sense but...there's more

```
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    int doubled_value;
public:
    Derived() : 
        Base {}  {
            cout << "Derived no-args constructor " << endl; 
    }
    Derived(int x) 
        : Base{x} , doubled_value {x * 2} { 
            cout << "int Derived constructor" << endl; 
    }
    Derived(const Derived &other)
        : Base(other), doubled_value {other.doubled_value} {
         cout << "Derived copy constructor" << endl;     
    }
```

In this code above which is from a different video that is part of the course, at line 10 where he writes **:Base{x}** he says he is delegating to the Base class's constructor which is where i'm confused cuz he used curly brackets and in line 14 where he writes **:Base(other)** he says he is delegating to the base class's copy constructor and he used parenthesis here so i'm getting quite confused....
Does using parenthesis or curly brackets matter?
**And How does the compiler know when he is referring to the copy constructor or normal args constructor?**

And this is the base class in case u need it

```
private:
    int value;
public:
   Base()
        : value {0}  { 
            cout << "Base no-args constructor" << endl; 
    }
    Base(int x) 
        : value {x} { 
            cout << "int Base constructor" << endl;
    }
    Base(const Base &other) 
        : value {other.value} {
         cout << "Base copy constructor" << endl;     
    }
        
    Base &operator=(const Base &rhs)  {
    cout << "Base operator=" << endl;
        if (this == &rhs)
            return *this;
        value = rhs.value;
        return *this;
    }
            
   ~Base(){ cout << "Base destructor" << endl; }
};
```

This is the derived class

```
private:
    int doubled_value;
public:
    Derived() : 
        Base {}  {
            cout << "Derived no-args constructor " << endl; 
    }
    Derived(int x) 
        : Base{x} , doubled_value {x * 2} { 
            cout << "int Derived constructor" << endl; 
    }
    Derived(const Derived &other)
        : Base(other), doubled_value {other.doubled_value} {
         cout << "Derived copy constructor" << endl;     
    }
    
    Derived &operator=(const Derived &rhs) {
            cout << "Derived operator=" << endl;
        if (this == &rhs)
            return *this;
        Base::operator=(rhs);
        doubled_value = rhs.doubled_value;
        return *this;
    }
   ~Derived(){ cout << "Derived destructor " << endl; } 
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between C-like, constructor, and uniform initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization)

Comment: In order to make C++ even more "interesting", it matters in some cases but not always.

Comment: @molbdnilo but how will the compiler know that he is referring to the copy constructor or normal constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

The choice of brackets is not what determines whether you're delegating to another constructor or not.

The choice of brackets isn't entirely arbitrary, and [it can make a difference to some things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24953658/4386278), but not for this.

It's unfortunate that the code's author has chosen to be confusing, by mixing initialisation styles, without even writing a comment to explain why they've done so.

Comment: But how does the compiler know when he is referring to copy constructor or normal constructor?

Comment: @Padawan The constructor chosen depends on the arguments, just like any function.

Comment: @Padawan _"But not for this"_ - the greedyness of overload resolution for choosing overloads (constructors as well as for free functions) whose argument has a matching `std::initializer_list` argument is notorious, and something you'd eventually want to know about. Had the author of your example wanted to implement overloaded constructors in `Base` with `std::initializer_list` argument(s), the choice between using direct list init vs direct initialization invocation makes a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, and by speculation of the authors intent; no, using *direct list initialization* (`Base{x}`) as compared to *direct initialization* (`Base(other)`) *should* make no difference. We cannot know for sure, however, as we have not seen the implementation of `Base`.

When it comes to initialization, specifically overloading of constructors, there are significant differences between list initialization and non-list initialization: the former strongly favouring constructor overloads with a matching parameter of type `std::initializer_list<T>`.

E.g., consider this contrived *and evil* example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    int value{666};
public:
    Base(std::initializer_list<int>) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }
    Base(int val) : value(val) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
    int doubled_value;
public:
    DerivedA(int x) : Base(x),  doubled_value(2 * x) {}
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
    int doubled_value;
public:
    DerivedB(int x) : Base{x},  doubled_value(2 * x) {}
};

int main() {
    DerivedA a{42}; // OK a.value is 42, a.doubled_value is 84
    DerivedB b{42}; // EH? b.value is 666, b.doubled_value is 84
}
```

Comment: how is a.value 42 when u set value as 666 by default

Comment: @Padawan That is the whole essence of my answer: because in `DerivedB b{42};` the constructor of `DerivedB` contains the expression `Base{x}`, which uses _list initialization_, thus choosing the `Base(std::initializer_list<int>)` of `Base, which _does not make use of the value passed to it_, this falling back on the default member initializer `{666}` to the `value` data member of `Base`. For the example `DerivedA a{42};`, the call to the `Base` constructor does not use list initialization (`Base(x)`) and thus the `Base(int val)` is chosen, initializing `value` with the passed argument.

Comment: @Padawan Ah, you may mean why a default member initializer is not always chosen? The default member initializer is _only chosen for constructors where the same data member is not present in any member initializer list_, as is the case with the `Base(std::initializer_list<int>)` constructor (no member initializer list).

Comment: i understand most of what u just said, but i dont know what std::initializer_list<int> means, i'm referring to the comment before this latest one u posted cuz as soon as i sent my comment, it showed the new one u sent

Comment: and why does the constructor of derivedb take Base(std::initializer_list<int>), why does it having Base{x} make it choose Base(std::initializer_list<int>)