# What is the difference between X() and X{}

Tags: c++

I know the X{} is the default initializer from internet, and I still don't know what the X() means what. is it initializer? but why the `int value();` is not
ok?

so I want to know what difference is between X() and X{}. thank you!

```
class X{
public:
    void operator()(string str)
    {
        cout << "calling functor x with parameter" << str << endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    X foo;
    // foo("hi");
    X()("hi");      // I don't know what happen when I see the code
    X c = X{};      // this is the default initializer 
    X a = X();      // but what it is
    int value{};
    // int value(); // this is error
}
```

Comment: `int value();` is a declaration of a function that takes no arguments and returns an `int`. Braced initialization was introduced to distinguish this situation and ones like it that arise with more complicated combinations of types.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization)

Comment: You are asking a complicated question. There do exist different kinds of initialization in c++. I suggest you reading this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization and the `see also` part.

Comment: [cppreference.com - Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: `X()` and `X{}` are all Value initialization because they have no any parameter. `X(param1, param2)` is List initialization and `X(param1, param2)` is Direct initialization. Well, it's complicated but you needn't make them all very clear. You can simply make the `X{}` as your prior choice.

Comment: With regards to why `int value();` is not OK: [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/)

Comment: A lot is going on a here. Key words are `uniform initialization`, `most vexing parse`, and `call operator`.