# How does pair get constructed from an initializer list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, std-pair

Types like array, vector, and map can be constructed from an initializer list like `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};`

This is good because the initializer list and the vector both have a single type.

I want to know how `std::pair<int, std::string> p = {1,"text"};` works. It's not possible for it to be through the initializer list because that must have a single type.

I have heard of piecewise construct, but I don't see how that fits here either.

Comment: *Uniform* Initilization

Comment: You can do `auto p = std::pair<int, std::string>{1,"text"};`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization

Answer (score 1):

It calls the two argument constructor of `pair` which then calls the single argument constructors of each specific type.

The compiler will choose a constructor with an initialization list if:

1. It has a constructor with an initialization list
2. It fits the requirements of an initialization list (All elements are of same type)

std::pair does not satisfy either requirement so it finds a constructor with matching argument types.

This is the constructor it calls for `pair` from `stl_pair.h` (gcc 11.2)

```cpp
explicit constexpr pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)
      : first(__a), second(__b) { }
```

Since C++17 You can use the following statement too:

```
std::pair p = {1,"text"};
```

One thing I would point out is that you are using **copy list initialization** because of the equal sign rather than **direct initialization**.  This can have some side effects but probably won't.

Good reading here:[Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: `std::pair p = {1,"text"};` wouldn't create a `std::pair<int, std::string>` though but a `std::pair<int, char const *>` or `std::pair<int, const char[5]>`