# Different methods C++ object initialisation

Tags: c++

Are these three lines of code (that have obviously the same effect) strictly equivalent?

```cpp
std::string bar("foo");
std::string bar = "foo";
std::string bar{"foo"};
```

or is it just a matter of style? To me `std::string bb = "bb";` is the variant that looks the most "natural".

Comment: The first one is direct initialization, 2nd is copy initialization and 3rd is list initialization.

Comment: Since C++17 these are all required to do the same thing.  Before that the `=` case could create a temporary.

Comment: You can refer to the [standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4950.pdf). Also [Is there a difference between copy-initialization and direct-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051379/is-there-a-difference-between-copy-initialization-and-direct-initialization)

Comment: [This initialization reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) might be helpful to read.

Comment: *"To me std::string bb = "bb"; is the variant that looks the most "natural"...."* That is subjective and opinion based.

Comment: @user12002570 absolutely, that's why I wrote "to me".

Comment: This is the better dupe, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953658/what-are-the-differences-between-c-like-constructor-and-uniform-initialization

Comment: @sweenish I added that in.  I think keeping the other one is good since it has some extra detail about list initialization.

Comment: Nothing wrong with multiple resources.

Comment: You're touching the topic of this cppcon presentation [The nightmare of initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs). In general I prefer using "uniform initialization" because it detects the most issues (however it is not perfect either).